# Solving second order ODE: $y''+y'^2=2e^{-y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving second order ordinary differential equation: $y''+y'^2=2e^{-y}$

I can't really identify the correct technique for solving this type of questions...

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any ideas yourself?

Comment: **Hint :** $~e^{^{\LARGE y(x)}}=Ax^2+Bx+C$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

suppose $$u = e^y, y = \ln u, y' = \frac {u'} u, y'' = \frac{u''}u - \frac{u'^2}{u^2}$$ the differential equation $y'' + y'^2 = 2e^{-y}$ is transformed into 
$$ \frac{u''}u - \frac{u'^2}{u^2} + \left(\frac {u'} u\right)^2=\frac2u$$ so that $$u'' = 2$$ which is easier to solve. i hope you can go from here.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This is a perfectly respectable answer.

Comment: @SimonS, thanks. it is hard to figure the down voters.

Comment: Thank you! how come $u''=2$?

Comment: oops, nevermind! Thanks!!!

Comment: How did you come up with this substitution?

Comment: i think the $e^{-y}$ on the right hand side helped. but, as change of variable go, it is mostly chance.

Answer (score 0):

$e^y(y'') +e^y(y')^2 =2
\implies d(e^y y') =2$

On integration
$e^y(y') =2x+c \implies  e^y dy =(2x+c)dx$

It can be easily solved

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for finding out about how write mathematical formulas.